# Google Tag Manager: Calling dataLayer.push after validating the form

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I want to call below code (Google Tracking code) if the form is validated successfully.

onclick="dataLayer.push({'event': 'NewsletterSignup'});"

If I add it to "onclick" event, it fires every time without considering the validation.

please let me know how should I call it only after validating the form. I searched in Google Tag Manager developer guide but could not find any help regarding this.

Please advise.

Comment: How do you validate the form?

Comment: This form uses a client side validation based on prototype library. The validation function returns true if validation pass. So is it OK to include "dataLayer.push({'event': 'NewsletterSignup'});" part if validation true? or do you have any suggestions?

Please advise.

Comment: Since you have a validation function that returns true why are you looking for another option?

Comment: Reason is not sure about how these tracking codes work. Do I need to add it in the validation or do I need to add it on a new page after I submit the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you need is to change your onclick handler to include the validation. Something like this:

```
onclick="function() { if(validate_form()) dataLayer.push({'event':'NewsletterSignup'}); }"
```

I'm not a Javascript programmer so I hope that's the correct syntax. All I've done is to introduce the validation check into the onclick. If the check passes we push the event to the data layer (I assume that `validate_form()` returns a boolean).

Your idea of firing the tracking code on the new page after the form is submitted is another possibility. That could work. You could just add a rule in GTM for that tag (tracking code) that causes it to fire on the new page (assuming that the *only* time that the new page is loaded is after a newsletter signup has occurred).

I think using the onclick handler above is the simplest solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer...I will test it and let you know